# Google Apps Scripts - How to add a two adjacent columns together then display the new value to the next column automatically for multiply sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to be able to add all numbers in Column F - Male and Column G - Female to the Number of Passengers automatically using Google Apps Scripts.

[image: The picture below]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically you don't need app scripts to automatically do have a dynamic column of ranges summed. You could put this formula in cell H2 and it will autopopulate... `=Filter(F2:F+G2:G,F2:F<>"")`

If you wanted to create an app script to apply this to all sheets (**EDIT**: only sheets whose name is in the array `sheetNamesToChange`) ... you could do this:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc*/

function runMacro() {
  const sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets();
  sheets.forEach(addFormula_);
}

function addFormula_(aSingleSheet) {
  const theFormulaToUse = '=Filter(F2:F+G2:G,F2:F<>"")';
  const theAddressToUse = 'H2';
  const sheetNamesToChange = [
    'Sheet1',
    'Sheet7',
    'Sheet9'
  ];

  //tests to see if aSingleSheet name is in the array sheetNamesToChange
  if (sheetNamesToChange.includes(aSingleSheet.getSheetName())) {
    //if yes, applies formula here
    aSingleSheet.getRange(theAddressToUse).setFormula(theFormulaToUse);
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you, This work perfectly for all the sheets in the doc. I just don't need the formula to apply to all sheet,  but to some selected sheets in the google sheets.

Comment: @KasimUsman thanks for accepting. I updated the code to include an option to list out names of sheet you wish to apply the change to. See the variable `sheetNamesToChange`

Comment: Thank you, it works... But on the selected sheets, I don't want it to calculate when the CELL (F2 and G2) is empty, check this link in the qoute- "drive.google.com/file/d/1kRZHYLCncRXZN00SAdE4NUTaEjTjly6p" I don't want the "#N/A" there, but when F2 and G2 is filled then it should input the Addition in H2. Thank you.

Comment: Just use an iferror or an if statement to account for a blank cell.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches you can use.

Asuming you want to sum F1+G1 and display on H1 and so on.

You can set the value of the H column to be the corresponding SUM formula, or you can set the value to the result of the sum and do that in your code. The latter being slightly easier and more readable.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];


//the input would be the letter of the columns you want to aggregate
//start row dictates from which row you want to begin.
//adjacentColumn would be where the results are written. 
function aggregateColumns(column1, column2, startRow, adjacentColumn){
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    for(let i = startRow; i < lastRow; i++){
        var value1 = sheet.getRange(`${column1}:${i}`).getValue();
        var value2 = sheet.getRange(`${column2}:${i}`).getValue();
        sheet.getRange(`${adjacentColumn}:${i}`).setValue(value1+value2);
    } 
}
```

If you're unable to specify the adjacent column before hand, then you'd have to either translate A1 notation to row and column numbers, or simply use row and column numbers from the start.

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];


//Column inputs should be the column number. Index starts at 1
//start row dictates from which row you want to begin.
function aggregateColumns(column1, column2, startRow){
    let lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
    for(let i = startRow; i < lastRow; i++){
        var value1 = sheet.getRange(i, column1).getValue();
        var value2 = sheet.getRange(i, column2).getValue();
        sheet.getRange(i, column2+1).setValue(value1+value2);
    } 
}
```

I recommend you to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) if you don't want to bother with row, column indexes and want to use A1 notation instead.

Comment: Friendly suggestion (since you have global variables), consider including `/** @OnlyCurrentDoc*/` whenever possible for security purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Those are great options. However, you can also test this method:

```
/** @OnlyCurrentDoc*/

function SumColumn() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var dataRange = ss.getDataRange().getValues();

  var startRow = 1;
  
  for (var i=1; i <dataRange.length; ++i){
    var row = dataRange [i];
    var column1 = row [5];
    var column2 = row [6];
    var sum = column1+column2 ;

    ss.getRange(startRow+i,8).setValue(sum);

  }
  
}
```

The numbers in `row []` belong to the column indexing where `Column A` is `0`.

In your example, you are using  `Column F`, which corresponds to the number `[5]`, and  `Column G` to the number `[6]`.

However, the indexing of `getRange()` changes, and that one [starts from 1](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows).  So `Column A` is `1`, and for your case `Column G` is the number `8`.

**Reference**

- [Indexing using getRange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows)